# How to login in laravel using hash techniques

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I stored email & password like this:

```
  public function addNewUser(Request $request)/****Add new User****/
  {

      $user_email = $request->input('email');
      $user_hashed_pass = $request->input('password');
      $user_pass = Hash::make($user_hashed_pass);

      $addAdmin = new SaveNewUser(['useremail'=> $user_email, 'userpassword'=> $user_pass]);
      $addAdmin->save();
      echo "User added.";
  }
```

And trying to login like this:

```
public function userLogin(Request $request)/****Login User****/
  {
      $user_email_log = $request->input('email');
      $user_hashed_pass = $request->input('password');
      $user_pass_log = Hash::make($user_hashed_pass);

      $user = DB::table('userinfo')->where(['useremail'=>$user_email_log, 'userpassword'=>$user_pass_log ])->get();
      if(count($user)>0)
      {
         echo "Welcome User";
      }
      else
      {
        echo "Wrong email/password.";
      }
  }
```

But cannot login by correct email and password. I think for login hashing password technique is generating new characters for the password and so its not matching. Can anyone help me out here to how to login. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hash::make('password');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/hashing you can see that they have `Hash::check()` in "Verifying A Password Against A Hash"

```
if (Hash::check('plain-text', $hashedPassword)) {
    // The passwords match...
}
```

Or as in your case, it would look like this

```
$user = DB::table('userinfo')->where('useremail', $request->input('email'))->first();

if ($user === null) {
    return 'Wrong email';
}

if (Hash::check($request->input('password'), $user->password)) {
   return 'Welcome User';
} else {
   return 'Wrong password';
}
```

Comment: Why post the same answer?

Comment: Idk man, I'm new to this stuff, so I can't upvote your answer, tbh I wanted to upvote yours instead of creating a new one

Answer (score 1):

Your right, each time Hash:make() runs it will return a different result as some randomness is added. Use the Hash::check() function to check your plain text password against the hash stored in the database. for example, after recovering your user model using the email only, use the following to test the password.

```
if(Hash::check($request->input('password'), $user->password))
{
    echo "Welcome User";
}
```